# What does 套 mean in ...绝对没有一个规则套在这里...?

Tags: meaning

This is 俞敏洪 speaking:

> 这个问题两说，我建议想清楚了一件事情以后再去做，只要想清楚了，你就要不断往前， 只要资源允许，时间，能力没问题，你都要坚持去做。 这就和战争一样总是要看到当时当地的情况才能下决定，绝对没有一个规则套在这里，大家以后就不用去思考。

绝对没有一个规则[套]在这里
(there is) absolutely no rule/principle [hidden] in this,
(there is) absolutely no rule/principle [one can follow] here,
(there is) absolutely no rule/principle [applicable] here,

I know of：
套用规则：apply a rule
自动套用：auto format

What does this 套 mean here?

Comment: bkrs:〈动〉to cover
to encase, to sheathe 
(1) 罩在外面 [cover with; slip on]
下边穿着条香色洋布夹裤, 套着双青缎子套裤。 --《儿女英雄传》
(2) 如: 套袖(套在衣袖外保护衣服)
(3) 把棉花、 丝棉等平整地装入被褥或袄里缝好 [fit over]。 如: 套棉被; 套棉袄; 套进去; 套件衣服

Comment: cf. jukuu: 63. Where pipelines cross swamps, rivers, or lakes they may be encased in concrete. 油管跨越沼泽地，河流、湖泊时，可以用混凝土管匣套起来。64. A hangman's noose had already been placed around his neck. 一个绞刑的绳圈已经套在他的脖子上。

Comment: regarding answers: are there (more) examples online of abbreviating 套 to 套用 in a phrase of type NP套在NP里? Some users more or less agree with OP's choice #1, which agrees with the common meaning of verb 套 (cover, encase, sheathe), also note jukuu's 100 samples for 套在，many with 套在 NP 上。 regarding 套在 里， note
把谈话套在学术性探讨的框子里 (套在框子里frame in)

Comment: 套 means that limit an object or an animal  with a container, to avoid leaving or losing control. so 套用规则 means apply a rule or a standard to make sure things go right.

Answer (score 4):

My understanding is that 套 is short for 套用 here, meaning "apply mechanically".

Basically, the author conveys there isn't such a rule/principle that could work for all the circumstances, so that we don't have to worry once applying it.

With that in mind, I gather you should be able to wording it much better than I do as an English native.

This is my shot:
(there is) absolutely no rule/principle fixing(or being applied) here, so we don't have to worry about it any more.

On top of that, if the sentence is written as 绝对没有一个规则**被套用**在这里, would it be more understandable to you? In fact, it's a passive voice sentence with some omissions.

Answer (score 2):

In this context, '套' means "restrict" or "set"

- 规则(rule) is a form of **restriction**
- 规则(rules) are being **set** by people .

"被规则套着" = "be restricted by rule"

> 绝对没有一个规则[套]在这里
>
> There is absolutely no rule/principle [**is set**] here

He mentioned "it is like war, we can only make a decision after considering many different elements" suggested he meant "there's no set rules"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @dan's explanation on the meaning of 套, ie apply a rule mechanically without thinking, but I don't agree with his translation in the end.

I think the translation should be

There is no universal rule to be applied here and we can't apply any rule without thinking.

Answer (score 1):

套 means apply something blindly.

A: 我不会打排球.

B: 那你就把打篮球的方法套在这里.

when it is used as adjective, it means something that could be used blindly.

A: blablabla

B: 别跟我说这些套话.

It is usually negative.